# Why the extra information getting added to the Excel file which is to be downloaded using PHP headers?

Tags: php, excel, http-headers, download

I'm writing PHP array data to the excel file using some library. When I write the data to the excel file and echo some success message, it works fine. No other data than the intended array gets added to the file.

But when I use headers to make the download of same file functionality workable some additional information present on page (like header menu, some heading, copyright line at bottom of page, etc.)gets added to the file. How to avoid adding this extra information to the excel file? Following is my code:

```
<?php
  require_once( CORE_PATH."/libs/excelwriter.inc.php" );

  $objRebateReports   = new RebateReports();

  if($_POST['btnDownload']!='') {
    $rebate_ret = $objRebateReports->GetRebateReport($_POST);
    $rebate_data = $objRebateReports->GetResponse();

    $t=time();

    $fileName = ADMIN_ROOT."modules/rebates/rebate_report_".$t.".xls";

    $excel = new ExcelWriter($fileName);      

    if($excel==false) {
      echo $excel->error;
      die;  
    }       

    $myArr = array('Sr. No.', 'Product','Manufacturer','User Name','Date','Status','Transaction Date');

    $excel->writeLine($myArr, array('text-align'=>'center', 'color'=> 'red'));

    $id=1;

    foreach ($rebate_data as $value) {

      $temp_rebate_data =array();

      $temp_rebate_data['id'] = $id;
      $temp_rebate_data['product'] = "";
      $temp_rebate_data['manufacturer'] = "";            
      $temp_rebate_data['user_name'] = $value['customer_first_name']."".$value['customer_last_name'];
      $temp_rebate_data['date'] = $value['created_at'];
      $temp_rebate_data['status'] = $value['request_status'];
      $temp_rebate_data['transaction_date'] = "";

      $row = $temp_rebate_data;
      $excel->writeLine($row, array());
      $id++;
  }
  $excel->close();

  //Following is the header information in order to download the excel file

  header("Content-Type:   application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$fileName);
  header("Expires: 0");
  header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
  header("Cache-Control: private",false);

  //Below is the success message after printing the data successfully to the file
  //echo "Data written to file $fileName Successfully.";                 
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use output buffering for this.

```
        //start of the page

        ob_start(); 


        //ur code

       //headers

       ob_clean();
       flush();
       readfile($file);
        exit;
```

I think this  will solve your problem